# Are function propotypes obsolete in c++

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, function-definition, function-declaration, function-prototypes

I am looking at an old book and it contains function prototypes. For example:

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
int main()
{
    int square(int); //function prototype

    for(int x = 0; x<=10; x++)
    {
        cout<<square(x)<<"";
    }

    int square(int y)
    {
        return y * y;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, on newer C++ tutorials, i don't see any function prototypes mentioned. Are they pbsolete after C++98?
What are the community guidelines for using them?

Example: https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/trycpp.asp?filename=demo_functions_multiple

Comment: If you removed `int square(int);` you would get a compiler error. Because square is not known at `cout<<square(x)<<"";`

Comment: C++ lets you define functions within functions within functions.  Is this actually a thing now?

Comment: In your example project at the link move the implementation of `void myFunction() {` to after `int main()` and see what happens.

Comment: The C++ nomenclature tends to be "function declaration", rather than "prototype". They're still used.

Comment: @selbie gcc extension probably. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html It does say it isn't supported in C++ though, so who knows?

Comment: @drescherjm It says that the function was not declared in this scope.

Comment: If the book you're reading really does define (implement) the `square` function *inside* the `main` function, you should throw it away. You probably should do it anyway if it's old enough to be before the C++ standardization. [Here's a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) of more modern books.

Comment: ***It says that the function was not declared in this scope.*** That is the reason why in modern c++ we still need function declarations and the answer to your question is No they are not obsolete.

Comment: @selbie Actually that functionality was added in C++11, as lambdas... ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - lambda yes. But not like the above, right?   At least not on the Visual C++ compiler I have in front of me.  But maybe g++ ?  What's actdually standard vs extension here?

Comment: @selbie No "normal" functions like that are not allowed to be nested. As I said if that's in the book then it should be thrown away.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - About once a month, I see someone post some C++ code that makes me question if I actually know this programming language or not. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters defining a function within another function like this

```
int main()
{
    //...
    int square(int y)
    {
        return y * y;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

is not a standard C++ feature. You should define the function `square` outside main.

If you will not declare the function `square` before the for loop

```
int square(int); //function prototype

for(int x = 0; x<=10; x++)
{
    cout<<square(x)<<"";
}
```

then the compiler will issue an error that the name `square` is not declared. In C++ any name must be declared before its usage.

You could define the function `square` before main like

```
int square(int y)
{
    return y * y;
}

int main()
{
    //...
}
```

In this case the declaration of the function in main

```
int square(int); //function prototype
```

will be redundant because a function definition is at the same time the function declaration.

> What are the community guidelines for using them?

A function with external linkage if it does not have the function specifier `inline` shall be defined only once in the program. If several compilation units use the same function then they need to access its declaration.

In such a case a function declaration is placed in a header that is included in compilation units where the function declaration is required and the function definition is placed in some module.

Answer (score 2):

They're not obsolete but they would mostly be in header files rather than *.cpp files.

They may be called "forward declarations" by some C++ tutorials (such as learncpp.com). Here's a page talking about them: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/forward-declarations/